# How do I solve this integral. The second part throws me off

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I just started doing integration and I dont know what the curly bracket(f(x)= 4 for x<4 etc...) means:[image]

Comment: The more interesting problem (for me at least) which platform was this question from?

Comment: @Chinny84 looks like WebAssign to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\int_a^b f(x) dx = \int_a^c f(x) dx + \int_c^b f(x) dx$. IN this case, take $a=0$, $b = 8$ and $c=4$. And then use the appropriate part of definition of $f(x)$ on each interval -- between $0$ and $4$ it is $4$, and between $4$ and $8$ it is $x$.

So, the integral is $\int_0^4 4 dx + \int_4^8 x dx$.

Comment: What is the answer? I got 20 but it is wrong. Any idea? I used the property of the integrals for the constant term..4(4-0) + 8-4 = 20

Comment: @Chris your computation of second integral is false. The antiderivative of $x$ is not $x$.

Answer (score 5):

> I dont know what the curly bracket(f(x)= 4 for x<4 etc...) means

That's called a **piecewise function**, because it's defined in pieces.  It's typically prerequisite knowledge for calculus, so definitely make sure you understand it before moving too much farther.

The piecewise function you provided says:

$$
\text{If $x < 4$ then the value of $f(x)$ is $4$.}
$$
$$
\text{If $x \ge 4$ then the value of $f(x)$ is $x$.}
$$
For example, $f(2) = 4$ because $2 < 4$ and $f(12) = 12$ because $12 \ge 4$.

So to integrate it, split up the integral at $x=4$ as explained in Batman's answer.